# RoR render partial not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having a trouble running this code as partial from a different view. However, if I try to access it directly that means *0.0.0.0:3000/posts/_dashboard* it works. From the different view I am getting this `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def _dashboard
       @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

view under posts/_dashboard.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
<%= p.title %>
<%= p.description %>
<%= p.image %>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get "/site/home", to: "site#home"
  get "/posts(/:action)", to: "posts#posts"

  resources :posts
end
```

In a different view

```
<%= render partial: "posts/dashboard" %> %>
```

Comment: You need to set `@posts` in the `Controller.action` where you are trying to render the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass posts to your partial:

```
<%= render partial: "posts/dashboard", posts: @posts %>
```

Edit your partial:

```
<% posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.title %>
  <%= p.description %>
  <%= p.image %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller's action of the page where your partial is rendered, add:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

Comment: `@variables` are shared between controller action and _all_ views used in the render process. `@posts` should be available in every partials used in the rendering process of the controller's action setting this `@posts` variable.